# Null Propagation Error In Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to deploy a cloud function where I'm reading from my database. I want to validate a field exists deep in an object so I was trying to use the null propagation operator **?.**

**Expected Behavior**: if a deep key doesn't exist (or anything along the path), the expression below returns *undefined*.

**Example Code:** `if (doc.data()?.key?.subKey?.subSubKey) { // Do Stuff }`

When I deploy, I'm getting an error.

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

**Clear Problem Statement**

Am I doing something stupidly wrong? Are **?.** permitted in cloud functions? Its just vanilla JS right?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Its a general question but I'll edit to include a code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in the MDN docs. From there it seems that it was implement in Node.js version 14, so you're likely using an earlier version either for your Cloud Functions runtime or somewhere in your deployment pipeline.

You'll either have to compile your code down to as supported version, or write the expression fully (which is what a transpiler will do):

```
if (doc.data() && doc.data().key && doc.data().key.subKey && doc.data().key && doc.data().key.subKey?.subSubKey) { // Do Stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

The node version I was using, mismatched the one I specified in my `package.json`. You can check which version you are using by running the following in your terminal:

```
node --version
```

I changed the version with nvm to the appropriate one.